# Отправка письма в html и txt одновременно

Tags: php, sendmail

Всем привет, в одной статье по рассылкам была рекомендация слать сразу несколько типов писем (html и txt), чтобы на разных устройствах, клиентах письмо точно нормально отображалось.

Собственно вроде как это возможно если я все правильно понимаю, но как это сделать я так и не нашел. В сети попадаются примеры с отправкой либо только обычного текста, либо html.

Как совместить это и отправить через функцию mail() в php ? Возможно у вас есть пример ?

Comment: отправьте письмо дважды да и дело с концом, в одном случае собирайте тело с заголовками html в другом голым текстом

Answer (score 1):

Речь идёт о [`multipart/alternative`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.4) значении заголовка `Content-Type`. Этот вариант позволяет описать несколько вариантов одного содержимого и является частью `multipart` письма.

Функция `mail` в php слишком низкоуровневая для таких вещей. Поэтому вам необходимо либо самостоятельно сформировать всё письмо согласно всем релевантным `RFC` либо воспользоваться готовой библиотекой. Например, [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) позволяет сформировать `msgHTML` и указать `AltBody`, который будет отправлен текстовой альтернативой для этого HTML.

Ну а я если очень хочется, то читайте `RFC`, на один документ я ссылку указал и процитирую из него письмо с несколькими альтернативными форматами отображения:

```
 From: Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com>
 To: Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com>
 Date: Mon, 22 Mar 1993 09:41:09 -0800 (PST)
 Subject: Formatted text mail
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary42

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

   ... plain text version of message goes here ...

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: text/enriched

   ... RFC 1896 text/enriched version of same message
       goes here ...

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: application/x-whatever

   ... fanciest version of same message goes here ...

 --boundary42--
```